# How do I export environment variables using a script in the same shell in python?

Tags: python, shell, scripting, operating-system

My django project fetches credentials from environment variables, now I want to automate this process and store the credentials in the vault(hashivcorp).
I have a python and shell script which fetches data from an API and exports it as environment variables, when I run it using os.system command it runs the shell script but as it runs it in a subprocess, I can't access the variables in the main(parent) process/shell. Only way of doing it by inserting the shell script in the settings.py file.
Is there any way I can do it so that I get those in the main process?
P.s: I did try sourcing, os.system didn't recognise it as a command.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
import os

os.environ['ENV'] = 'Demo'
os.system('python3 /home/rishabh/export.py')

print(os.environ.get('RDS_DB_NAME'))
```

output:

```
None
```

the python file, shell script works just fine.

Comment: Why do you want to run `export.py` as a child process, and not inside your main process? But if you really want to do it, you could (inside export.py) create a text file which contains the environment variables you are interested in, together with their values, and then process this file in the main script.

Comment: I also suggest that you remove the _shell_ tag from your question, because there is nothing shell specific in it.

Comment: I was looking for a way to run it that way only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to run `export.py` in the same process, as *user1934428* suggested:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['ENV'] = 'Demo'

sys.path.append('/home/rishabh/')
import export   # runs export.py in the same process

print(os.environ.get('RDS_DB_NAME'))
```

This assumes there are no `__name__ == '__main__'` checks inside `export.py`.

You only need the `sys.path` line if `export.py` is in a different directory than your current script.

Comment: It didn't cross my mind that I can even do it this way. Thanks a lot for the help! :D